# Running a task on a single host always with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a task to download a database dump from a specific location. It will always be run on the same host.

So I am including the task as follows in the main playbook:

```
tasks:
  include: tasks/dl-db.yml
```

The content of the task is:

```
---
   - name: Fetch the Database
     fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/mydb.sql.gz dest=/tmp/mydb.sql.bz fail_on_missing=yes
```

But I want it to fetch from a single specific host not all hosts.

Is a task the right approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need to happen is that it's only run once rather than on every host you can instead use [`run_once`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) like so:

```
---
   - name: Fetch the Database
     run_once: true
     fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/mydb.sql.gz dest=/tmp/mydb.sql.bz fail_on_missing=yes
```

This will then be run from the first host that runs the task. You can further limit this with `delegate_to` if you want to specifically target a specific host:

```
---
   - name: Fetch the Database
     run_once: true
     delegate_to: node1
     fetch: src=/home/ubuntu/mydb.sql.gz dest=/tmp/mydb.sql.bz fail_on_missing=yes
```

Comment: `hosts` is not a valid attribute for a Task